# Using function calls in constructor initializers

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

Imagine that I have a class with a member that does some work on a vector when it's instantiated, and the class does not have a default constructor:

```
struct Header
{
    static const Header & Read(uint8_t * & buffer, size_t & length);
    Header( some params );
}

class C
{
private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<uint8_t>> mBuffer;

public:
    Header header;

    C(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<uint8_t>> p_buffer) :
        mBuffer(p_buffer),
        header(Header::Read(p_buffer->data(), p_buffer->size()))
    {}
};
```

This quite reasonably fails to compile, as data() and size() are not lvalues.

I could add additional member variables to represent the vector's first element and length, and pass those to Read():

```
class C
{
private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<uint8_t>> mBuffer;
    uint8_t * head;
    size_t length;

public:
    Header header;

    C(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<uint8_t>> p_buffer) :
        mBuffer(p_buffer),
        head(p_buffer->data()),
        length(p_buffer->size()),
        header(Header::Read(head, length))
    {}
};
```

But this seems awfully hokey. Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: A `vector` knows its own size, so why does `Read()` need to return a new length? To report the actual number of bytes written to `buffer` if smaller than the length requested? If so, then you have to keep track of that new length anyway, so you need a separate variable for that (and then optionally `resize()` the `vector` afterwards to match).  But as for the `buffer`, there is no reason to pass it by reference unless `Read()` can change it to point at a different memory address, so just remove the `&` from the `buffer` parameter and then you can pass `p_Buffer->data()` directly to `Read()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a straightforward problem with the signature of the `header(...)` requiring lvalues for its parameters. This can be fixed by adding a `static` function that calls through to the original header without requiring lvalues, like this:

```
class C
{
private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<uint8_t>> mBuffer;
    static const Header& ReadStatic(uint8_t *buffer, size_t length) {
        // You can call Header::Read now, because when it comes to passing lvalues,
        // function parameters are fair game:
        return Header::Read(buffer, length);
    }
public:
    Header header;

    C(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<uint8_t>> p_buffer) :
        mBuffer(p_buffer),
        header(ReadStatic(p_buffer->data(), p_buffer->size()))
    {}
};
```

This lets you get rid of the two members that were actually stand-in temporaries that you added for the purpose of calling `Header::Read`.

Comment: When I try this I get a warning: "C4505: 'ReadStatic' : unreferenced local function has been removed." This seems to indicate that this is dead code, and the compiler optimized it out. Does that make any sense to you? I should mention that I put the implementation of ReadStatic in the Header struct instead of C, if that makes any difference.

Comment: @fatcat1111 Are you sure that you put it inside the header `struct`, as opposed to the header *file* in which the `struct` has been defined? The error message suggests that `ReadStatic` is a regular, i.e. non-member, function. This is OK, too, but in this case you should replace `static` with `inline`.

Comment: Oops, that's exactly what I did. You have mad programming skills plus psychic debugging skills to boot. Thank you!